# UILocalizedIndexedCollation with custom sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting

Lets say i have an object called animal with 2 fields called species and breed.

I have some objects where the species is dolphin and some where the species is dog.

I want to have sections divided up by species, thus i would have sections for dog and dolphin and the D in the section index titles (the alphabet slider on the right hand side to quickly navigate) would go to dog since g comes before l in the alphabet.

i currently have my objects sorted into sections based upon the species, but by default the UILocalizedIndexedCollation has sorted the dog and dolphin objects into the "D" section and the species of dolphin and dog are all jumbled together within the section (though sorted alphabetically).  How would i go about implementing the functionality i want?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it turns out that i can implement my own version uilocalizedindexedcollation that does the things i want.

i just need to have these basic properties and functions and i can make it do just about anything i want.

```
// Provides the list of section titles used to group results (e.g. A-Z,# in US/English)
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *sectionTitles;

// Provides the list of index titles used to quickly jump to particular sections
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *sectionIndexTitles;

// Specifies the section that should be scrolled to for the title at the given index.
// This method allows you to map between a given item in the index
// and a given section where there isn't a one-to-one mapping.
- (NSInteger)sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:(NSInteger)indexTitleIndex;

// Returns the index of the section that will contain the object.
// selector must not take any arguments and return an NSString.
- (NSInteger)sectionForObject:(id)object collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector;

// Used for sorting objects within the same section.
// selector must not take any arguments and return an NSString.
// In the process of sorting the array, each object may receive
// selector multiple times, so this method should be fast.
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayFromArray:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector;
```